# How to change the position when the parent is resized?

Tags: qt, qml

How do I properly change the x, y of an object so that it changes its position when the parent is resized? There is, I will introduce that if I drag the rectangle to the middle, then when the window is resized, it should remain in the middle. (middle for example only, rectangle can be moved freely)

[image: Example]

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

onWidthChanged: {
            block.x -= block.previousWidth - width
            block.previousWidth = width
        }

onHeightChanged: {
            block.y -= block.previousHeight - height
            block.previousHeight = height
        }

    Rectangle {
        id: block
        color: "red"
        width: 50
        height:50
        x: 100
        y: 50

       property int previousWidth: 0
       property int previousHeight:0

       Component.onCompleted: { 
          previousWidth = parent.width
          previousHeight  = parent.height
}

        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: block
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain your use case with some images.

Comment: The best and right solution is using [anchoring](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-positioning-anchors.html#:~:text=Each%20item%20can%20be%20thought,is%20the%20same%20as%20top.). QML is declarative language, you shouldn't implement some imperative practices. Let the engine do the work, just explain what you want to get.

Comment: @folibis, _rectangle can be moved freely_, so anchoring won't work, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I must admit, at first I was not impressed by the question. However, when I thought about it, it represents a very interesting and valid use case. So I would be happy to provide a solution.

### Solution

I would approach the problem like this:

1. Make the frame a child of the background image.
2. Instead of manually calculating the coordinates, use `Item.scale` to scale the image, effectively preserving the relative position of the frame with regard to the image.

### Example

Here is an example I have prepared for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Image {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        source: "alphabet.png"
        scale: parent.width/sourceSize.width

        Rectangle {
            id: frame

            width: parent.width/7
            height: parent.height/4
            border.color: "black"
            color: "transparent"
            antialiasing: true

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                drag.target: parent
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

The example produces the following result:

Original window

[image: Original window]

Resized window

[image: Resized window]

The frame is moved

[image: Moved frame]

The window is resized again

[image: Moved frame and resized window]

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, the best solution is anchoring, for example:

```js
Window {
    id: root
    width: 600
    height: 400
    title: qsTr("Parent window")
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint

    Grid {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Repeater {
            model:  16
            Rectangle {
                width: root.width / 4
                height: root.height / 4
                color: Qt.rgba(Math.random(),Math.random(),Math.random(),1)
            }
        }
    }
    Rectangle {
        border {
            width: 5
            color: "black"
        }
        color: "transparent"
        width: root.width / 4
        height: root.height / 4
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: root.width / 4
        anchors.bottomMargin: root.height / 4
    }
}
```

Comment: In my case, the rectangle can be moved absolutely freely using drag.

Comment: so what do you want to preserve? x and y? width, height? is that relative to the parent size or absolute?